# How to force driver for 22.04.4 to run with Intel Arc?

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, intel-graphics

I am completely new to dual booting Ubuntu with Windows and Linux in general. Now I just downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.4 with Rufus and did the disk partitioning of 30 GB (went safe) and everything that all the guides told me to. But after starting Linux and getting to the "Try or Install Ubuntu" screen and pressing enter my computer just gets a permanent terminal error screen after like 10 seconds. The error message is:

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: 
Your graphics device 7d55 is not properly supported by i915 in this kernel version.  
To force driver probe anyway, use i915.force_probe=7d55.
```

Nothing I press on the terminal screen does anything. I can only manually power down the laptop and the run Windows.

I have no idea how to do the "force driver" thing. Anyone have a very dumbed down step-by-step guide as to how to force the driver without already having ubuntu only having windows?

[The terminal screen that gets stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEEGC.jpg)
edit 1: I tried 23.10, it boots into a loading screen with HP logo and ubuntu logo at the bottom but is stuck there as well. Waited for at least 20 min. and saw no progress so i don't think that works either.

edit 2: I tried 24.04. daily build and it didn't work either. The daily build of 24.04 filename: "noble-desktop-amd64.iso" did not work. Where do I write "i1915.force_probe=7d55" so i can try forcing  driver on 22.04.4? And pls dumb it down as much as y'all can, i'd greatly appreciate it

edit 3: As @emk2203 pointed out my description of 24.04 wasn't very fulfilling so I tried booting 24.04 after the comment to have a description for the problems. I entered grub and pressed "Try or Install Ubuntu". After waiting 41 min. on one screen(I timed it) that didn't show any errors I could see(see image 2)[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDWnu.jpg) I retried again, now writing "nomodeset" after "quick splash" in grub(read some articles about graphics driver bypassing). This made the process progress a bit, but now it got stuck on a new screen that read "Unable to find a medium containing a live file system". I put the USB in and out, used an adapter, and tried it all again, but still no luck.

The interactive netboot from a URL didn't work either. I just pressed enter for all the prompts for the default answers but it just ended up writing "dhcpcd exited" and then freezing

If anyone has any solution please let me know. I've spent so many hours because of this Intel Arc thing

edit 4:

I used "i915.force_probe=7d55" after writing it in grub with both 22.04.4 and 24.04(daily build). Neither worked. Both got stuck at the "live file system" error or just another terminal screen without any obvious errors. I used another USB that just dual booted and it showed same error with the daily build from 16/03/2024

I think I'll wait till 24.04 LTS releasing 24 April 2024 and just use VMware or WSL2 until that. Thanks for the help everyone, I'll try and update this if it works.

Comment: Can you give Ubuntu 23.10 a try and let is know if it works out if the box?

Comment: Even though it is still in development, you might need to try 24.04. It seems Arc is only supported as of kernel 6.6 and later. See [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2496006).

Comment: I tried 23.10, it boots into a loading screen with HP logo and ubuntu logo at the bottom  but is stuck there as well.  Waited for at least 20 min. and saw no progress so i don't think that works either.

Comment: I'll try the daily build of 24.04 and let you know how it goes

Comment: The daily build of 24.04 filename: "noble-desktop-amd64.iso" did not work. couldn't i force driver with 22.04 and then download kernel? If so how do i force driver? Where do I write" i1915.force_probe=7d55"? And dumb it down as much as y'all can pls

Comment: What do you mean 'did not work'? Same issue as with 22.04.4? The live flash medium did boot and show the graphical environment, or not?

Comment: @emk2203 I've updated my question with a more in-detail look at the issues with 24.04. Hope you can help:)

Comment: When grub shows up, press `e`. You will get a screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnUQa.png). There, write `i1915.force_probe=7d55` after `quiet splash`. Press `F10` or `ctrl + x` to proceed. Let us know if it boots with that

Comment: It didn't. Updated my question for further descriptions. Thanks for all of your help

Comment: You got another, serious, underlying issue. There is no way that an error of live system file error can have anything to do with the graphics driver, or the ARC GPU itself.
You need to get a good, known, flash drive, check it with h2testw on Windows, and write the image with i. e. Balena Etcher, to make sure that the on-disk image is without errors. And download 24.04 again to get the latest version. It now contains kernel 6.8, which supports your ARC GPU.
No need to force probe.

Comment: I followed your instruction with the newest 24.04 but my laptop still shows the live file system error. H2testw showed no errors either. I'm blank on what else to do

Comment: @emk2203 I even used a different USB stick that just dual booted on another pc, maybe 24.04 just has a bug or something?

Comment: This is baffling. Try another distro which has the latest drivers just to see if it is Ubuntu or not. Something not Debian-based, you could try CachyOS, or some rpm-based SUSE distro (Tumbleweed?). Make sure that they have kernel 6.8.